# tomcat7 - jdbc datasource - This is very likely to create a memory leak

Tags: mysql, spring, memory-leaks, tomcat7, datasource

I get the following messages in catalina.out log file when tomcat is shutdown. I am using Tomcat 7.x and the Tomcat JDBC data source.

```
Mar 26, 2013 1:17:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc 
SEVERE: The web application [/my_webapp] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered. 
Mar 26, 2013 1:17:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads 
SEVERE: The web application [/my_webapp] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

The first one claims that the DataSource has been forcibly unregistered so that is fine. However it is strange Because I have configured the destroy-method like so:

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

Not sure why I get the second one. The one about the "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer".

Any help is appreciated

EDIT 1:
I tried the fix suggested by @Zelldon and it gets rid of the first error. However the `MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer` related issue still persists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve memory leak problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615118/how-to-solve-memory-leak-problems)

Comment: See this comment to learn more about the MySQL Cancellation Thread issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46733027/185565

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47019335/3408531

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to put the sql Connector/Driver in the tomcat/lib and not in the war.
Because every time you deploy the war the connector/driver will be created sometimes the garbage collector cant remove them which will ends in a memory leak. So try to move the connector on the tomcat/lib folder.

Please read the following answers:

[Why must the JDBC driver be put in TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981564/why-jdbc-driver-must-been-put-in-tomcat-home-lib-folder)

[How to configure Tomcat to connect with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485177/how-to-configure-tomcat-6-0-with-mysql)

Comment: are you using also other libray's?

Comment: nope. The DataSource is the one provided by Tomcat 7. The Driver is from MySql Connector/J. On top of that, I have Spring JDBC but I guess that has nothing to do with this issue. Other than that, there are no other database related libraries.

Comment: ah i found something please check out the following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615118/how-to-solve-memory-leak-problems   same error on the first line, the answer is... it is a bug of mysql http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36565 please update your mysql connector jar file

Comment: yup I figured this as well. It updated the connector jar and it works fine now. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to this bug in the MySQL jdbc connector: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65909.

You can wait for the MySQL team to fix it, or you try to use the [Drizzle JDBC connector](http://www.drizzle.org/content/download) which works fine with MySQL (you have just to change the parameter in the url connection) and, in my tests, doesn't have this kind of bug.

Comment: drizzle site is down

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem just like you ,and I just roll back the pom version of mysql-connector-java from 8.0.16 to 8.0.15 and the problem got resolved,I think it's the unmatch between the version of connector and mysql that caused the problem