# The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, memory-leaks

In the middle of my web-development I just close my web-app in my eclipse IDE, about a minute, I just saw a **WARNING** in my eclipse console.

```
WARNING: The web application [/Spring.MVC] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 06, 2014 8:31:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [/Spring.MVC] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:40)
Sep 06, 2014 8:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Sep 06, 2014 8:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 06, 2014 8:32:03 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: personPU
    ...]
```

It did not caused any memory leak so far, I checked my VisualVM, everything is working as usual, but as I search more about this thing I realize that this warning is caused by the MySQL driver not releasing resources or not being closed properly(I dont know how to say it exactly) and I ended up in this post at SO [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872316/tomcat-guice-jdbc-memory-leak)

and the OP is right  *the answer of "don't worry about it" won't be sufficient*. This warning bothers me because it may give me some **future persistence problems** and that worries me a lot, I tried the code the OP has written but I'm having a problem **what Libraries** should I use to make this code work. This is what I got sor far..

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.impl.LoggerFactory;
import com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread;
@WebListener
public class ContextFinalizer implements ServletContextListener {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContextFinalizer.class);

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
    Driver d = null;
    while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
        try {
            d = drivers.nextElement();
            DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
            LOGGER.warn(String.format("Driver %s deregistered", d));
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOGGER.warn(String.format("Error deregistering driver %s", d), ex);
        }
    }
    try {
        AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.warn("SEVERE problem cleaning up: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to know what Libraries do I need or If I'm using the right libraries to implement this properly, I do not even know what Logger should I use, thank you for any help,

Comment: The logger is not necessary to the solution. Did you run your code? What happened? Do you still see the warning?

Comment: thank you for the response, I was not able to run it, I did not know that the logger isn't necessary for this code, I just restarted my computer before I try this, Ill post back in case something different will happen. thank you. :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I just finished trying the sample code above, without logger(thanks for that), and yes it is working, `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread` is being shutdown, however, as I'm monitoring the server in my VisualVM, the permgen space is still being occupied and I'm still ending up with a memory leak, I still need to perform a manual `GC`. But as for the code, yes it is working.

Answer (score 32):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632153/tomcat7-jdbc-datasource-this-is-very-likely-to-create-a-memory-leak). It seems that MySQL driver should be in `{$TOMCAT]/lib` shared between applications. Check that you are not including it with each application. At least it worked for me and I have been able to remove the warning.

If you are using Maven mark the dependency as provided.

**UPDATE:**
root cause is that Tomcat have problems to garbage collect the driver because it is registered in a singleton common to several applications. Closing one application does not allow Tomcat to release the driver. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198049/16206).

Comment: Can anyone expand this a bit more? Is this a bug related to a specific jdbc driver version?

Comment: Hi mass. See the update. There are more information in the links from other stackoverflow answers.

Comment: @borjab Marked the dependency as `provided`. but problem in starting server as i have configured db connection in `servletcontextlistner`. Any solution? Also done `<scope>provided test</scope>`, but failed.

Comment: Have you added the MySQL driver to your tomcat libs?

Comment: @borjab No. oh..I misunderstood `provided`. Now added. But it shows `AbandonedConnectionCleanup..` on `ContextDestroyed`. Used `provided` scope for `mysql-connector` in `pom.xml`

Comment: Was de jar added into $tomcat/lib? so that it is common to all apps?

Comment: @borjab yes. `apache-tomcat-8.0.37\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar`

Comment: I have included `<scope>provided</scope>` in my pom.xml and I got this exception `ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'`. I'm using hibernate5 so using this driver.

Comment: @RamanujanR I have copied the mysql jar file from my m2 repository to tomcat lib folder and error is gone.

Comment: I am using the mysql-connector-java version 8. It appears this has a dependency (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.21), would I place the jar for the dependency in the `[$TOMCAT]/lib` folder as well? Or should that go in my application's classpath?

Answer (score 2):

For me i stop mysql (service mysql start) and then i stop tomcat (./shutdown.sh) in bin folder and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error running the following command:

`systemctl status tomcat10.service`

It shows the specific error that was failing.

PS. I'm using a Debian OS, MariaDb and Tomcat10.

Answer (score -5):

**This works for me**.

Issue was with elastic search in my case.

Send a **DELETE** request from postman to below endpoint and restart your application .

```
http://localhost:9200/*
```