# Mojarra-WebResourceMonitor-1-thread-1 memory leak

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee, tomee-7

For the issue of

```
The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it.
```

I have solved it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26261752/4541141) answer, but there is another memory leak which remains unsolved:

```
The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Mojarra-WebResourceMonitor-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

May I know what is the cause of this memory leak and how to solve it?

Below is the list of libraries I use:

- jsf-api 2.2.13
- jsf-impl 2.2.13
- mysql-connector-java 5.1.31
- TomEE 7.0.4

Comment: which version of tomee?

Comment: Check the documentation for Mojarra. There is probably a background process that you simply need to stop when your application is being shut-down (e.g. using a `ServletContextListener`).

Comment: @MitchBroadhead TomEE 7.0.4