# The web application [gestionMines] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it

Tags: tomcat, mysql-connector

I get this worning every time I reload tomcat. What seems to be the problem?

```
 Mar 21, 2019 3:26:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
    INFO: Reloading Context with name [/gestionMines] has started
    Mar 21, 2019 3:26:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
    Mar 21, 2019 3:26:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    Mar 21, 2019 3:26:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
    WARNING: The web application [gestionMines] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    Mar 21, 2019 3:26:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
    WARNING: The web application [gestionMines] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
     java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
     com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The web application \[\] appears to have started a thread named \[Abandoned connection cleanup thread\] com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699985/the-web-application-appears-to-have-started-a-thread-named-abandoned-connect)

Comment: i'm using maven the jar get stored automatically. if i changed it's location when i ran the maven update it will download it again as if it was deleted.

Comment: You should add `<scope>provided</scope>` to that dependency. It will then not be added to your project deployment as it is considered to be `provided` by the runtime environenment.

Comment: @[medbouaddi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11237376/medbouaddi): I hope that you solved your problem.