# Getting org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query in Spring application after some time of application working fine

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I am having an application running fine using Spring+Hibernate+MySQL ,But some times i am getting these errors

error:

```
could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
```

I am running my aplication on tomcat - 7 version

so if i dont use the application for more than some time i am getting this error i dont know the time , if i restart my application then i am able to work fine i am not getting any error's

my database.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">



<bean id="dataSource" 
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
   <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
   <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Is there any thing wrong in the above configuration i need to change to fix this issue

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: even if i change the code i need to wait for the time to get the error which i dont know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198049/5193194) answer , You have to put the mysql Connector/Driver in the `Tomcat/lib` and not in the war. As every time you deploy the war the connector/driver will be created sometimes the garbage collector cant remove them which will ends in a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

you can see a similar problem and a possible solution on this topic.

[tomcat7 - jdbc datasource - This is very likely to create a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632153/tomcat7-jdbc-datasource-this-is-very-likely-to-create-a-memory-leak)